# Images displaying incorrectly in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

When I run my iOS app in simulator after updating numerous images within the application the images being displayed are still the old one.  What must be done in order to properly update the images loaded into the simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try Xcode menu:product:Clean
if not enough go to Xcode preferences:locations tab: 
click on the little gray arrow below derived data

then in the finder selected folder delete all files...